# Creating an associated model instance along with the primary instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Creating an associated model instance along with the primary instance

When I create a car, I need it to have a key as well.  I do both within the Car#Create action.  Is that correct or not?  What errors could it cause?  How should it be done?

While this works, it just doesn't appear to be Rubyist, or RESTful, to me.  Not that I am a stickler for that, but I want this to be right. Thanks...

```
  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)
    @key = Key.new(key_params)
    if @key.save and @car.save
      flash[:notice] = "Car has been created."
     else
      @key.destroy unless @key.nil?
      @car.destroy unless @car.nil?
      flash[:alert] = "Car has not be created."
    end
    redirect_to cars_path
  end
```

Comment: When you say Car#Create action are you referring to the "create" action of your controller (in REST style) or to the "create" method of the Car model? I ask primarily because Class#method is often how instance methods are referred to in Ruby. (Edit--tl;dr) what class is this method a part of?

Comment: Clarify: the key created should belong to the car? the car has only one key?

Comment: @acsmith I am talking about the create action of the car controller, yes.

Comment: @mvidaurre Yes, the car has one key and the key belongs to the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification then:

```
def create
  @car = Car.new(car_params)
  @car.build_key(key_params)
  if @car.save
    flash[:notice] = "Car has been created."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Car has not be created."
  end
  redirect_to cars_path
end
```

In your Car model you should have something like this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :key, dependent: :destroy
  // all your other code
end
```

In the way you were doing the association between the `car` and the `key` was not specified.

Comment: Would it be true then that saving the car saves the key simultaneously and, if it fails, neither would exist?  I am assuming that build_key is simply that as a Car method.

Comment: Please review the Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference `build_key` is a Rails meta-programing method for ActiveRecord that is the parent of the Class Car.

Comment: Yes, I did recognize that after the comment.  I have used it but did not recognize the implications.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'm glad to help answering your question

Comment: Is there a similar pattern for simultaneous updates?  I just don't see one and wondering if I am missing it.

Comment: Do you mean something as car.update(car_params)? Check this: http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Comment: I mean that I need to do a @ car.update_attributes and a @ car.update_key, but I don't see the update_association method listed.

Comment: No. For Rails 4 `update_attributes` is deprecate use `update`. You should do something like this: `@car.update(car_params)` and `@car.key.update(key_params)` use `key` usually by is `car`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a validation in your Car model that a key exists for it and in an `after_create` create the Key for it.

```
def create
  @car = Car.new(car_params, key_params)
  if @car.save
    flash[:notice] = "Car has been created."
   else
    @car.destroy unless @car.nil?
    flash[:alert] = "Car has not be created."
  end
  redirect_to cars_path
end
```

Then inside your car class you should have something like this:

```
class Car
  validates_presence_of :key
  after_create "create_key(key_params)"

  def create_key(key_params)
    self.key = Key.new(key_params)
  end
end
```

This is all pulling from memory so if something doesn't match up quite right let me know and I'll try fixing it.